# What is the relation between $f'_+(a)$ and $f'(a+0)$?

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

For a function $f(x)$ defined on an interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$, where $\delta>0$, we define:
$$f'_+(a)=\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to0^+}\frac{f(a+\Delta x)-f(a)}{\Delta x}$$
and
$$f'(a+0)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f'(x).$$

I've been told that, if both $f'_+(a)$ and $f'(a+0)$ exist, they must be the same value.

I want to know why.  Can anyone can give a proof for this?

Comment: Just be careful with "as we know," because I've never seen either of those notations before.

Comment: Let's hear how do you define $f^\prime(x)$? As far as I can see, both of your definitions stated in the question are exactly the same thing if you're using the definition of $f^\prime(x)$ as $f^\prime(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Comment: If the derivative exists, that means the function is continous and therefore $f'_-(a)$ is the same as $f'_+(a)$ and consequently so is f(a)

Comment: @WillFisher: The one-sided derivative $f_+'(a)$ can exist without continuity of $f$ except a one-sided continuity of $f$ at $x=a$.  The one-sided limit $f'(a\; + \; 0)$ requires the derivative $f'(x)$ to exist on some one-sided interval above $x=a$, so this requires more continuity than the one-sided derivative does.

Comment: @hardmath Yes but he said if $f'(a)$ and $f'_+(a)$ exist, why are they the same. And if $f'(a)$ that makes the assumption that the function is continous and then by the definition of continuity, the double sided limit $f'(a) $ must equal the corresponding single sided limit $f'_+(a) $

Comment: @WillFisher What I mean is why $f'_+(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a+}f'(x)$, given they both exist, not $f'_+(a)=f'(a)$.

Comment: @pjs36 thx, these notations are often used in Calculus textbooks in China.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement for $f'_+(a)$ to exist is that $f$ has one sided continuity at $x=a$. This doesn't imply it has two sided continuity, however if you then assert that $f'(a)$ exists you are then asserting that $f$ is continous at $x=a $. Then by the definition of continuity it must be that $\lim_{x \to a +}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a -}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and therefore $f'_{-}(a)=f'_{+}(a)=f'(a)$.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asserting "that $f'(a)$ exists".  Both the constructs $f_+'(a)$ and $f'(a\; + \; 0)$ are one-sided limits (from the right).  Indeed it is not necessarily a given that $f(x)$ is defined for $x\lt a$.

Comment: I think this answer totally misunderstood my question. $f(x)$ is continues on $x=a$ doesn't imply $f'(X)$ exist.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer. Assume $f'(x)$ exist on $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$, then by Lagrange mean value theorem, for $\Delta x\in(0,\delta)$, there exists a $\xi\in(a,a+\Delta x)$, such that
$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(a+\Delta x)-f(a)}{\Delta x}.$$
It's easy to see that $\xi\to a^+$ while $\Delta x\to 0^+$, so we have
$$f'_+(a)=\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+\Delta x)-f(a)}{\Delta x}=\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0^+}f'(\xi)=\lim\limits_{\xi\to a^+}f'(\xi)=f'(a+0).$$